# Extract a string of words between multiple specific words in R

Tags: r, lapply, gsub

I have a long string that includes one or multiple keywords, "Realm" in this case. I have been using gsub, but that only takes the words after the last of the keywords.

so the string could look like:

`...Attributes  \r\n      Realm - Afrotropical  \r\n  IUCN Ecosystem -- Terrestrial biome...`

or

`...Attributes  \r\n      Realm - Afrotropical  \r\n   Realm - Neotropical  \r\n .  IUCN Ecosystem -- Terrestrial biome...`

I have been using the function:

```
Realm_fun<-function(x){gsub('^.*Realm -\\s*|\\s*IUCN Ecosystem.*$', '', x)}
```

then using `lapply` to fun it on all of the strings.

what can I do to get `Afrotropical` for the first string and `Afrotropical , Neotropical` for the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
stringi::stri_extract_last(st, regex='(?<=Realm - )(\\w+)')
```

`stri_extract_last` will pull the last match for the regex, using a look behind assertions we can collect word followed by look arounds(using positive look behind in this case), in this case you are having words **Afrotropical** and **Neotropical** followed by **Realm -** .

In case if you want to extract both strings for last match, you can try below(`stri_extract_all`):

```
stringi::stri_extract_all(st, regex='(?<=Realm - )(\\w+)')
```

**Input**:

```
st <- c("...Attributes  \r\n      Realm - Afrotropical  \r\n  IUCN Ecosystem -- Terrestrial biome...", 
"...Attributes  \r\n      Realm - Afrotropical  \r\n   Realm - Neotropical  \r\n .  IUCN Ecosystem -- Terrestrial biome..."
)
```

**Output**:

```
> stringi::stri_extract_last(st, regex='(?<=Realm - )(\\w+)')
[1] "Afrotropical" "Neotropical" 


> stringi::stri_extract_all(st, regex='(?<=Realm - )(\\w+)')
[[1]]
[1] "Afrotropical"

[[2]]
[1] "Afrotropical" "Neotropical"
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how exactly you need the words to be. But one idea could be:

```
  regmatches(st, gregexpr("Realm - \\K(\\w+)",st,perl = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "Afrotropical"

[[2]]
[1] "Afrotropical" "Neotropical"
```

If you do not want to split the words:

```
trimws(gsub("(?m)^.*Realm - (\\w+)|((?!Realm).)*$","\\1 ",st,perl=TRUE))

[1] "Afrotropical"                "Afrotropical  \nNeotropical"

gsub("(?m)^(?:(?!Real).)*$|[\r\n]|.*Realm - ","",st, perl = TRUE)

[1] "Afrotropical  "              "Afrotropical  Neotropical  "
```

Answer (score 0):

Use base functions `gregexpr` and `regmatches`.

```
library(magrittr)

test<-c("...Attributes  \r\n      Realm - Afrotropical  \r\n  IUCN Ecosystem -- Terrestrial biome...","...Attributes  \r\n      Realm - Afrotropical  \r\n   Realm - Neotropical  \r\n .  IUCN Ecosystem -- Terrestrial biome...")

test %>% gregexpr("(?<=(Realm - ))[a-zA-Z]+", ., perl = T) %>% regmatches(x = test) 

#[[1]]
#[1] "Afrotropical"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Afrotropical" "Neotropical"
```